# List Remove - I run always in "List Index out of bounds"

Tags: apex, list

First, I add all rows of my Mail into a list. If the Listitem is also a item of my set then I want to remove this item list.
I tried to remove items from my List "RestMail", but the code below removed the from item from the list. If I change the code from i-- to i++ I run always in "List Index out of bounds".

I tried also to change the remove line into RestMail.remove(eMailBodyRows - i) but I run also in the error.

```
    IF(email.plainTextBody != Null && email.plainTextBody != '') {
        String[] emailBodyRows = email.plainTextBody.split('\n');
        List<String> RestMail = new List<String>();         

        Set<String> fieldimport = new Set<String>{'firstname', 'phone_private'};              
            FOR (Integer i = (emailBodyRows.size()-1); i >= 0; i--) {
                RestMail.add(emailBodyRows[i]);
                 FOR (String fi : fieldimport) {                  
                     IF (emailBodyRows[i].contains(fi)) {
                         String fieldName = fi + '__c';
                         RestMail.remove(i);
                         c.put(fieldName, emailBodyRows[i].substringAfter(fi));
                     }
                 }
            }                  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're counting down, RestMail[i] will always be out of bounds, unless i = 0. In addition, if more than one field matches, you again run into the error.

You may want to instead initialize to the maximum size, then assign instead of adding to the list, and remove the element when done with the loop. Or, simply don't add the value until you're done with the loop.

```
List<String> RestMail = new List<String>(emailBodyRows.size()); 
// ...
        FOR (Integer i = (emailBodyRows.size()-1); i >= 0; i--) {
             Boolean shouldAddRow = true;
             FOR (String fi : fieldimport) {                  
                 IF (emailBodyRows[i].contains(fi)) {
                     String fieldName = fi + '__c';
                     shouldAddRow = false;
                     c.put(fieldName, emailBodyRows[i].substringAfter(fi));
                 }
             }
             if(shouldAddRow) {
                 RestMail.add(emailBodyRows[i]);
             }
        }
```